# Cumilative sum for only consecutive date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumsum

Im trying to apply cumilative sum for column `Amount` only when date is consecutive in `Date` column :

Current input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': {0: 'USA',1: 'Canada', 2: 'China',3: 'Egypt',4: 'Poland',5: 'UK',6: 'Jordan'},
                   'Date': {0: '2021-01-01',1: '2021-01-02',2: '2021-01-03',3: '2021-01-04',4: '2021-01-06',5: '2021-01-07',6: '2021-01-08'},
                   'Amount': {0: 10, 1: 15, 2: 10, 3: 20, 4: 25, 5: 30, 6: 10}})

    Country  Date        Amount
0   USA      2021-01-01  10
1   Canada   2021-01-02  15
2   China    2021-01-03  10
3   Egypt    2021-01-04  20
4   Poland   2021-01-06  25
5   UK       2021-01-07  30
6   Jordan   2021-01-08  10
```

Expected output :

In row number 4 the cumilative sum is reset due to missing 2021-01-05 in `Date` column.

```
    Country  Date        Amount Cumilative
0   USA      2021-01-01  10     10
1   Canada   2021-01-02  15     25
2   China    2021-01-03  10     35
3   Egypt    2021-01-04  20     55
4   Poland   2021-01-06  25     25<
5   UK       2021-01-07  30     55
6   Jordan   2021-01-08  10     65
```

What i have tried, which is incorect :

Im not sure how to include a check in my script to check wheather `Date` column is consecutive to reset cumilative sum in `Amount` column.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Cumilative'] = df['Amount'].cumsum()


    Country Date        Amount  Cumilative
0   USA     2021-01-01  10      10
1   Canada  2021-01-02  15      25
2   China   2021-01-03  10      35
3   Egypt   2021-01-04  20      55
4   Poland  2021-01-06  25      80
5   UK      2021-01-07  30      110
6   Jordan  2021-01-08  10      120
```

Wwould appreciate if someone could help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df['Cumilative'] = df.groupby(df['Date'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum())['Amount'].cumsum()
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
  Country       Date  Amount  Cumilative
0     USA 2021-01-01      10          10
1  Canada 2021-01-02      15          25
2   China 2021-01-03      10          35
3   Egypt 2021-01-04      20          55
4  Poland 2021-01-06      25          25
5      UK 2021-01-07      30          55
6  Jordan 2021-01-08      10          65
```

This groups the dates into groups of consecutive dates and applies `cumsum` to the `Amount` column in all of the groups.

Comment: That worked Thanks!, will this work for multiple missing dates ?